# Honeycomb puzzle with hexagons

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Can you place the numbers 1 through 9 in the honeycomb so that the sum of the numbers in the adjacent hexagons is a multiple of the number in the hexagons? This must be true in all hexagons.

The top green hexagon is a 3.

[image: puzzle]

I've made several attempts but can't figure it out myself.
What is the method to solve such puzzles?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution I found:

> [image: 1]
>
> This works because:
>
> 4 + 7 + 6 + 9 = 26 = 0 mod 1
>  9 + 6 + 8 + 5 = 28 = 0 mod 2
>  7 + 6 + 8 = 21 = 0 mod 3
>  7 + 1 = 8 = 0 mod 4
>  8 + 2 = 10 = 0 mod 5
>  7 + 3 + 8 + 1 + 9 + 2 = 30 = 0 mod 6
>  4 + 1 + 6 + 3 = 14 = 0 mod 7
>  3 + 6 + 2 + 5 = 16 = 0 mod 8
>  1 + 6 + 2 = 9 = 0 mod 9
>
> I suppose you could flip it horizontally which would still keep the 3 at the top and produce a valid solution as well. And if there was no requirement for the 3 to be at top, you could flip it vertically as well.

Comment: I verified via enumeration of all possibilities that this solution and its horizontal reflection are the only 2 solutions

Comment: How did you come up with that solution? Or is it just try and try again?